# How do i disable Windows 7 from taking screenshots?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, screenshot, virus-removal

My laptop keeps on taking screenshots. Several keys, when pressed, would take a screenshot, essentially functioning as the "prt sc" key as well as their main function (for example the key "H" would take a screenshot as well as type "H"). Even when moving the pointer to certain positions it would take screenshots. funny enough, the actually screenshot key - prt sc - doesn't work. It doesn't take screenshots.

I think this problem has to do with my keyboard that's going out. I thought it was a virus but i've used Malwarebyes and it's detecting nothing. I also got Avast running.

I've seen instructions online on how to disable the "prt sc" key, however that's not what i want to do. I want to prevent my computer from taking screenshots altogether. Like disable that feature. How can i do that?

And yes, i know i should be switching over to Windows 10. I am. Im just waiting for my files to finish backing up to cloud.

Comment: First test - use another keyboard.

Comment: I agree with trying another keyboard. You can also uninstall the Snipping tool (Snip 'n Sketch in Windows 10).

Comment: If you are using a driver that came from the keyboard manufacturer, uninstall it.

Comment: An external keyboard does not recreate the problem

Comment: Replace they keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Hotkeys should not help that much.

You can use softwares like [ScreenWings](https://schiffer.tech/#screenwings), but Using that is like a workaround, because this will keep screenshot taking apps run, and even take screenshots, but it would be blank. And also it is blocked by many AV/Firewalls, so it is not guaranteed it will be safe.

And if you though disable PrtScn key, still there will remain intelligent ways of screen capturing. Display in virtual machines like Virtualbox are drivers, which can be still captured. Or there are techniques like HDMI capture or Capturing (Even direct accessing) video over RDP. IrfanView can set delayed captures or even custom hot keys for capturing, as well as AutoHotKey.

Only Snipping tool and Snip and sketch isn't the only software for screen capturing, there are lots of available. I think some kind of Spyware is installed on your computer.

So, this is nearly impossible at all.

Comment: How does this actually answer the question? It just seems to be a bunch of random ideas ...

Comment: @DavidPostill because stopping to take screenshots are nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

To disable totally Print Screen, you may use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Use the following script:

```
PrintScreen::Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. If the script works well, to have it run on login
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

If this method does not work, you may try the registry update method of disabling
the key at a very low level. See the Stack Overflow answer at
[disable the printscreen keyboard option from windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28083171/165358).

However, if this is a hardware problem with your keyboard, it might need replacement.